# If I move a WinForms form using VB.NET code... its height also changes. But why oh why?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ide, visual-studio-2005, showdialog

In the VB.NET VS2005 IDE I size this form's height to 180.

When I run this code it displays A150 B150 C180.  (Not sure where the 150 comes from... or why it changes later.)

The form is still correctly displayed as 180 tall.

If I move the form's left or top position... this will change to A150 B150 C150
The form is incorrectly displayed as 150 tall

```
Debug.Print("A " & frmMy.Height)
frmMy.Left = 11   ' Changes to LEFT or TOP decreases the form's height by 30???
'frmMy.Top = 2
Debug.Print("B " & frmMy.Height)
Call frmMy.ShowDialog()
Debug.Print("C " & frmMy.Height)
```

Do I have something set in the VS2005 IDE that says "if you reposition this form... change its height too???

Comment: negative .. I already test it and it's result A180 B180 C180 .. there's something wrong in yours ..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate similar behavior by setting `AutoSize` to True and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.  Check if these settings were turned on inadvertently.